# Cases in which given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ there is some number $a$ where $f(a)=g(a)$

Tags: functions

If you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ what qualities do $f$ and $g$ need to share so that there is some number $a$ in which $f(a)=g(a)$.

Here are my thoughts: If $a$ exists then it can be thought of visually as a point of intersection of the two functions. Another thing is that if the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb A$ and the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb B$ then if $a$ exists $a \in \Bbb A$ and $a \in \Bbb B$. Another thing is that the ranges of $f$ and $g$ must also intersect at some point.

I can't think of any more conditions off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are more. As a side note, is there any general way for solving for $a$ if it exists or proving whether or not it does? Also what area of math would cover this type of subject?

Comment: Could you give an example of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:group-theory]?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little unfamiliar with the topics so I guessed.

Comment: I don't have any examples. This is mostly just thought, sorry. I can give counter examples though.

Comment: Are these functions between sets? Continuous functions between topological spaces? Linear functions from $\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$? (though this seems unlikely from context) Your question would have different answers in all of these contexts. Also one can restrict the domains of $f$ and $g$ to their intersection without meaningfully changing the question, so you can assume $f$ and $g$ are defined on the same set. Your question right now is so broadly stated as to be almost meaningless.

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking about 2 dimension space for my self, with the domains and ranges of $f$ and $g$ ranging form the real plain to the complex plain.